# Set context in Human Handoff event

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

When using the Send a handoff activity action in Composer, you can provide a JSON object within the Context property input box in the right hand pane of Composer.

How do you set these values from Composer at runtime? We'd like to pass information from the current conversation to the handoff activity and ultimate to the human agent.

[image: Composer Event Context]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've submitted this as a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/9357) in the BotFramework Composer project on github. It's been verified and replicated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding your question/scenario correctly; you can use interpolation in the object. So let's say you had some variables/properties in any of the [memory scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/ref-memory-variables?tabs=v2x) that have been set. Just specify those in the object using `${}`

So, for example you could have your object like so:

```json
{
  "customobject": {
    "userproperties": {
      "haircolor":"${user.haircolor}",
      "favoritefood": "${dialog.favfood}",
      "height": "${conversation.userheight}"
    }
  }
}
```

Where the properties for haircolor, favfood and userheight have been set in different scopes.

Comment: Yes, you understand the scenario. I'll add some info but this is exactly what I tried but it comes across as the text string "${user.Name}".  I'm digging into the json to determine where the event context is stored. It appears to be somewhere in the conversation memory.

Comment: Submitted and verified as a bug in botframework composer.